# How to join these Tables with

Tags: join

I want to join table Saleperson with Table Salevolume. The Logic of the join is:

- Table Saleperson has key: itemfrom and itemto, Table Salevolume has Key: Item. When the key "Item" from Salevolume is between the key "itemfrom" and "itemto" of saleperson, then i will make sume of salevolume, group by Saleperson
- The Key "accountfrom" and "accountto"  and "item" have sometime character at the end

Can you please help me ?

Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Saleperson](
[Saleperson] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
[itemfrom] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
[itemto] [nvarchar](4) NULL
)
insert into [dbo].[Saleperson]
values
('A','111H','112H'),
('B','122G','125G'),
('C','134F','137F'),
('D','117','119'),

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Salevolume](
[Item] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
[Salevolume] [int] NULL
)

insert into [dbo].[Salevolume]
values
('112H',30),
('113H',40),
('122G',30),
('134F',50),
('118',100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fist check if item's last charater is alphabet or not. if it is a alphabet then check whether numeric value and alphabet value of item is between that of numeric value and alphabet value of itemfrom and itemto respectively as shown below:

```
select p.Saleperson,sum(v.Salevolume)
from Saleperson p
inner join Salevolume v 
    on v.Item between p.itemfrom and p.itemto
    OR  (
        RIGHT(v.Item,1)  between 'A' and 'Z' 
        and RIGHT(v.Item,1) between RIGHT(p.itemfrom,1) AND RIGHT(p.itemto,1)
        and REPLACE(v.item,RIGHT(v.Item,1),'') between REPLACE(p.itemfrom,RIGHT(p.itemfrom,1),'') and REPLACE(p.itemto,RIGHT(p.itemto,1),'')
    )
group by p.Saleperson;
```